# Does magento 2 support invoicing based on amount?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, create-invoice, partial-invoice

I'd like the ability to create (and capture) an invoice based on a dollar amount rather than a quantity of items.

We are currently using the endpoint `/V1/order/{orderId}/invoice` to create invoices but there is no available parameter for the amount to be invoiced.  Is creating an invoice and specifying the amount possible via the rest API?

Comment: the way magento totals works is by using prices for the item in the order and these prices come from product price along with catalog price rules, promotions rules or tier price / discount.. As you can see prices are complicated. Now, all this can be overwritten, customised but you would need still to describe how the prices for your items need to render?

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a Custom price to an item, but, you still need to add a product quantity to an order for an invoice to be created. 
You can't modify the price directly at the invoice, you should modify the product price in the order (or Quote). That's not a limitation of the REST API, you can't do that even from the admin panel.